# Element and container same border radius but doesn't align well

Tags: css, border-radius

I'm trying to align a rounded link inside a rounded container at the bottom of it.

But even when the border-radius is the same on both elements, there's a small difference between them and is noticeable with high contrast colors.

[image]

Here's a jsfiddle of the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/rumeau/q349vse7/3/

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background:white;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.link {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <p>
  Content
  </p>
  <a class="link" href="#">Read more</a>

</div>
```

Is there any standard solution to this, so I dont have to use a workaround?..

Greetings.

Comment: you need 18px for the container

Comment: Thanks. I've tried, but a small white gap is still visible, which i think is because of the renderization of screen pixels. Close but still not what I was looking for. Anyways, this fixed radius (18px) responds to a calculation? or is just trying different radius sizes? Because I dont think this would work if inner element change its radius. What I was looking for is a dynamic calculation of the radius or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest such a solution:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: none; /* <----- add this it */
  border-radius: 16px;
  background:white;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.link {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <p>
  Content
  </p>
  <a class="link" href="#">Read more</a>

</div>
```

Comment: You pointed me in what seems the right answer for my question. Actually I tried adding a negative margin of the size of ther border of the container to the link.